# Hibernate Identifier Name is too long for MySQL Index

Tags: mysql, hibernate, inheritance, indexing, identifier

I have got a problem with inheritance and the index name generation. As example:
Multiple abstract classes, which are inherited from each other.

```java
@Entity
public abstract class LongClassName1 implements Serializable { 
... 
    @Index(name = "externalIdIndex")
    String externalId;
...
}

@Entity
public abstract class LongClassName2 extends LongClassName1 { ... }

@Entity
public abstract class LongClassName3 extends LongClassName2 { ... }

@Entity
public abstract class LongClassName4 extends LongClassName3 { ... }

@Entity
public class LongClassName5 { ... }
```

Now Hibernate generates an Index like `LongClassName5LongClassName4LongClassname3LongClassname2externalIdIndex`
which leads to an error message like `Identifier name 'LongClassName5LongClassName4LongClassname3LongClassname2externalIdIndex' is too long`

I've tried multiple hibernate naming strategies and also have overwritten the methods myself, but nothing has worked so far.

I'm using the hibernate version shipped with JBoss 7.1.1.

Auto generated indexes for the primary key are no problem.

Any ideas what i can do next?

Answer (score 0):

Did your try to manually stablish the index name using the @Table and @Index annotations?

```
@Table(appliesTo="tableName", indexes = { @Index(name="index1", columnNames={"column1", "column2"} ) } )
```

Comment: Hi, i don't want to set the index explicitly for every table, just for the abstract class.